# Display fullwidth leaflet map inside dashboard tab using bs4Dash

Tags: css, r, shiny, r-leaflet, bs4dash

I am using `bs4dash`. In one of the tabs I use `leafletOutput` to display a map, which needs to fill the whole `dashboardBody` (at least its width).

The following code works:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(bs4Dash)

body <-  dashboardBody(
 tags$head(
   tags$style(
     "#m {
         height: calc(100vh - 57px) !important;
     }"
             )),                                                 
   leafletOutput(outputId = "m")
)
body$children[[1]]$attribs$style <- "padding: 0px 0px !important" 

ui <- dashboardPage(
 dashboardHeader(title = "test"),
 dashboardSidebar(),
 body)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$m <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(-8.44, 39.55, zoom = 14) })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

When I introduce tabs:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(bs4Dash)

b <-  dashboardBody(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(
      "#m {
          height: calc(100vh - 57px) !important; padding: 0px 0px !important;
      }"
              )),
    tabItem(
      tabName = "tab1",
 #     style = "padding: 0px 0px !important",
      leafletOutput(outputId = "m")
  )
)
b$children[[1]]$attribs$style <- "padding: 0px 0px !important" 

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "test"),
 # dashboardSidebar(),
  
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(menuItem("Tab 1", tabName = "tab1")
    )),
  body = b)

server <- function(input, output) {
   output$m <- renderLeaflet({
     leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(-8.44, 39.55, zoom = 14) })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

it gives the error:

```
Error in `*tmp*`$children : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

When looking at the resulting webpage source for both cases, in the appropriatte sections, I get:
(Without tabs, working example)

```
<section class="content" style="padding: 0px 0px !important">
 <div class="leaflet html-widget html-widget-output shiny-report-size html-fill-item-overflow-hidden html-fill-item" id="m" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
</section>
```

(with tabs)

```
        <section class="content">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane container-fluid" id="shiny-tab-tab1">
            <div class="leaflet html-widget html-widget-output shiny-report-size html-fill-item-overflow-hidden html-fill-item" id="m" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
         </div>
       </section>
```

I tried the following tags inside dashboardbody, but none work:

```
  tags$head(
    tags$style(
      ".content {
          padding: 0px 0px !important;
      }"
    )),
  
  tags$head(
    tags$style(
      "#shiny-tab-tab1 {
          padding: 0px 0px !important;
      }"
    ))
```

In the browser inspector, in the tabs example, I am able to add `style="padding: 0px 0px !important` in front of `class=content`, and it works.

For me, https://unleash-shiny.rinterface.com/beautify-css has been of great help in terms of learning to use `css` in `shiny` apps, but in this case, I'm yet to find a solution.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your error.  Your code runs fine for me.  Perhaps you just need to restart your RStudio session.

Comment: I had a # in the line giving the error. I just uncommented it. Sorry.

Comment: There was a typo in the code. All solved.